# Weak star closure of unit sphere in dual space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space with its dual $X^*$. Let $S^*$ be the unit sphere of $X^*$. We have known that if $X$ (or $X^*$ ) is reflexive then the weak-star and weak topology of $X^*$ coincide and thus the weak-star closure (or weak closure) of $S^*$ is the unit ball. I have the following questions:

1. If  is reflexive, what is the weak-star sequential closure of $S^*$?
2. If $X$ is non-reflexive, what are the weak-star and weak-star sequential closure of $S^*$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the weak$^*$ sequential closure of $S^*$ contains $0$.  So there is a sequence $(f_n) \subseteq X^*$ with $\|f_n\|=1$ for each $n$, and with $f_n\rightarrow 0$ weak$^*$.  For $f\in B^*$ the unit ball, we seek a bounded sequence $(t_n)$ of scalars such that $f+t_nf_n \in S^*$ for each $n$, as then $f+t_nf_n \rightarrow f$ weak$^*$.  We can find such $t_n$ from the triangle inequality,
$$ \big| \|f\| - |t_n| \big| \leq \|f + t_nf_n\| \leq \|f\| + |t_n|, $$
and using that $t\mapsto \|f+tf_n\|$ is continuous.  Conclude: the weak$^*$-sequential closure of $S^*$ is all of $B^*$.

So, when is $0$ in the weak$^*$ sequential closure of $S^*$?

Here is an easy argument if $X$ is separable.  Then $X$ hash a countably dense subset $\{x_k\}$, then for each $n$ by Hahn-Banach we can find $f_n\in S^*$ with $f_n(x_k)=0$ for $k\leq n$.  Given $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is $k$ with $\|x-x_k\|<\epsilon$, and so for $n\geq k$ we have $|f_n(x)| = |f_n(x-x_k)| < \epsilon$.  Conclude that $f_n\rightarrow 0$ weak$^*$.

As [Dirk Werner](https://mathoverflow.net/users/127871/dirk-werner) points out, in the general case, we can use the Josefson-Nissenzweig Theorem which exactly says that any (infinite-dimensional) Banach space has the property we need: $X^*$ has a weak$^*$-null sequence of norm one vectors.  Here is one source for this theorem: [Extract from Diestel, Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-5200-9_13)

Comment: By the Josefson-Nissenzweig theorem, $0$ is in the weak$^*$ sequential closure of $S^*$ if $X$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks Mathew Daws and Dirk Werner for your wonderful solution and reference.

Comment: I am grateful to both of you if you are interested in the following question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427651/application-of-bishop-phelps-theorem