# Application of Bishop-Phelps Theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Consider a real Banach space $X$ and its continuous dual $X^*$. [The Bishop-Phelps Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Phelps_theorem) states that the set
$$A^*=\{x^*\in X^* \mid x^* \text{ attains its supremum on } \text{ the unit ball } \mathbb{B} \}$$ is norm-dense in $X^*$. Clearly, $\overline{A^*\cap \mathbb{S}^*} \subset \mathbb{S}^*$, with $\mathbb{S}^*$ be the dual unit sphere in $X^*$. Here $\overline{A}$ denotes the norm-closure of $A$. When $X$ is reflexive, $A^*=X^*$ (by [James's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27s_theorem)) and the equality
\begin{equation}
\overline{A^*\cap \mathbb{S}^*} = \mathbb{S}^* \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
holds.

1. Does the equality \eqref{1} holds in arbitrary non-reflexive spaces $X$?
2. If the answer is 1. is false, in which non-reflexive space $X$ that the equality \eqref{1} holds?

Thank you for your solutions.

Comment: I'm confused: let $f\in \mathbb{S}^*$ and by Bishop-Phelps you have $f_k\in A^*$ such that $f_k \to f$ in $X^*$. WLOG $f_k \neq 0$. Then isn't it the case that $f_k / \|f_k\|_*$ (here $\|\cdot\|_*$ denotes the dual norm) belongs to $A^*\cap \mathbb{S}^*$ and converges to $f$ in $X^*$? (Here we use that $A^* = \lambda A^*$.) Am I missing something in this sketch?